# Suspecting duplicate message from RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, nservicebus

i have service which uses NServiceBus to communicate with other services.
My problem is that i am supposed to get X amount of messages and i get X+1 or X+2 or X+3.
This problem occurs when the service is using multiple threads, but when i force this service to use a single thread, i do not have this issue.

I am suspecting RabbitMQ 'thinks' the message failed and resends it, or some other rabbit mechanism is at work here that sends me extra messages.

Are my suspicions valid?
Thank you.

Edit:
I now clearly see that i get the same message twice.

Comment: How did you diagnose this? By using breakpoints in the debugger?

Comment: If i debug the process runs perfectly, if i do not debug (and with multiple threads) i get those extra messages

Comment: I asked because sometimes while debugging your messages will timeout and end up in the retry. Are the message ids the same?

Comment: there's not enough information to know what's going on. please post code and configuration of rmq that reproduces the problem

Comment: @DerickBailey i refrained from posting code because it is extremely complex. This is why i tried to ask a more general question

Comment: This behavior could be possible if you use `auto ack = false`. In this case  the messages will be requeued if there is an error consumer side and you don't send the `basic_ack`.

Comment: Will this https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/rabbitmq/transactions-and-delivery-guarantees and https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/rabbitmq/ help?

Comment: StackOverflow is not really good for these type of "help my diagnose" issues. would it be possible for me to help you out on the NSB google groups site? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/particularsoftware